# How to post listview items through retrofit 1.9?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, post, retrofit

Here my doubt is how to post listview items to server through retrofit 1.9 here is my code :

Add.fragment:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;



import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.otto.Bus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 16-10-2015.
 */
public  class Add extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static ListView lv;
    public static LeadRequirementsView _LeadRequirements;
    static MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
    //   String TAG="Add";
    static Bus bus;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_btn_add, container, false);
//bus.register(getActivity());
            //Lead Source
            Spinner ldsource = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lead_source);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox1, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ldsource.setAdapter(adapter);

            //Lead Type
            Spinner ldtype = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldtype);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox2, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ldtype.setAdapter(adapter1);

            //Lead Status
            Spinner ldstatus = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldstatus);
            TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarget);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox3, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
            ldstatus.setAdapter(adapter2);


            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

          List<LeadRequirementsView> leadRequirementsViewList = new ArrayList<>();
            myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, leadRequirementsViewList);
            lv.setAdapter(myListAdapter);



            return rootView;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void updateListView(LeadRequirementsView object) {
        myListAdapter.add(object);

        myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button btnrequirements = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnrequirements);
        btnrequirements.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnactnt = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnacnt);
        btnactnt.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        Button btnprimary = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnprimary);
        btnprimary.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        Button btnsecondary = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnsecondary);
        btnsecondary.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnrequirements:
                Fragment newFragment = new NewRequirements();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, "NewRequire");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;

            case R.id.btnacnt:
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                SelectAccountDialog selectAccountDialog = new SelectAccountDialog();
              //  selectAccountDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
                selectAccountDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");
                //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
            case R.id.btnprimary:
                FragmentManager fmm = getFragmentManager();
                // FragmentTransaction ftt=fmm.beginTransaction();
                SelectAccountDialog selectAccountDialog1 = new SelectAccountDialog();
                //selectAccountDialog1.setRetainInstance(true);
                selectAccountDialog1.show(fmm, "fragment_name");
                //   ftt.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
            case R.id.btnsecondary:
                FragmentManager fm2 = getFragmentManager();
                //     FragmentTransaction fttt=fm2.beginTransaction();
                SelectAccountDialog selectAccountDialog2 = new SelectAccountDialog();
                //selectAccountDialog2.setRetainInstance(true);
                selectAccountDialog2.show(fm2, "fragment_name");
                //     fttt.addToBackStack(null);
                break;

        }

    }


}
```

This is my customlist adpter;

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 25-11-2015.
 */
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LeadRequirementsView> {

    private List<LeadRequirementsView> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<LeadRequirementsView> listdata) {
        super(context, resource, listdata);
  this.listData=listdata;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(LeadRequirementsView object) {
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public LeadRequirementsView getItem(int position) {

        return listData.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        View mview = convertView;
        if (mview == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ld_requirements,null);
            TextView req = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            req.setText("Select Lead Information");
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sbu);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bu);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sbuu);
            holder.ldstatusView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sc);
            holder.ldtype = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ssc);
            holder.ldsource = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rq);
            //   add.lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //    add.lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.headlineView.setText("Strategic Business Unit: " + listData.get(position).getSbuName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText("Business Unit: " + listData.get(position).getBuName());
        holder.ldstatusView.setText("Sub Business Unit: " + listData.get(position).getServiceCategoryName());
        holder.ldtype.setText("Service Category: " + listData.get(position).getServiceSubCategoryName());
        //   holder.ldsource.setText("Service Sub Category: " + listData.get(position).g);


        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E5E5E5"));


        // holder.headlineView.setText("Requirements: " +listData.get(position).getReq());


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView headlineView;
        public TextView reporterNameView;
        public TextView reportedDateView;
        public TextView ldstatusView;
        public TextView ldtype;
        public TextView ldsource;
        public TextView req;
    }
}
```

My doubt is my listview is getting populated from another fragment data which is dynamic but now what i should do is need to post this list items to the server how come i do this you guys are here to help can somebody resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion best way to send "data from list view" or List that populate that list view is to serialize list into JSON string with [gson](https://github.com/google/gson), and then use retrofit to send it to server.

```
public class Model {

public Model(String data1, String data2, String data3) {
    this.data1 = data1;
    this.data2 = data2;
    this.data3 = data3;
}

private String data1;
private String data2;
private String data3;
}
```

array list into json

```
    List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(new Model("name", "surname", "age"));
    models.add(new Model("name2", "surname2", "age2"));
    models.add(new Model("name3", "surnam3", "age3"));

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = gson.toJson(models);
```

and from this you get JSON like this

```
[{"data1":"name", "data2":"surname", "data3":"age"},{"data1":"name2", "data2":"surname2", "data3":"age2"},{"data1":"name3", "data2":"surname3", "data3":"age3"}]
```

Comment: then can i do like this new Gson.tojson(object);

Comment: sure and you will get json of your list, you have numerous JSON parsers on web, where you can check looks of your JSON

Comment: can't get it can you please just brief it